# Is it possible to transport a TCP connection over websockets or another protocol?

Tags: tcp, go, websocket, socks

I'm wondering, is it possible to transport/tunnel a TCP connection though the websockets protocol?

There is a [websockets package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) and it seems I could io.copy the TCP connection into the websockets connection but I don't know how to reassemble it as TCPConn on the other end.

For example I would like to create a socks5 
ServerN(behind NAT) on one end and a ServerIE on the other end. An internet user would make a socks5 request (though the socks5 protocol) to ServerIE and ServerIE would send the socks5 request through the websocket connection to ServerNAT. ServerNAT will then process the socks5 request(i.e. it's a socks5 server).

**EDIT:**
I've wrote some code but unfortunately it gets stuck on reading from the TCP connection into WS.   To run it: `go run main.go -logtostderr`

```
package main

import (
    "flag"

    log "github.com/golang/glog"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    "bufio"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
//  "io"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    defer log.Flush()
    log.Infof("wsServer()")
    wsCh := wsServer()
    log.Infof("wsNAT()")
    natWS, err := wsNAT()
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    done := make(chan struct{}, 1)
        log.Infof("listenTCP()")
        conn := listenTCP()
        buf := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    go func() {
        log.Infof("Write TCP to WS")
        n, err := buf.WriteTo(natWS)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            return
        }
        log.Infof("newConn.ws.ReadFrom(conn) %v", n)
        close(done)
    }()
    wsToTCP(<- wsCh)
    <-done
}
// wsNAT dials /ws endpoint and returns a websocket connection.
func wsNAT() (*websocket.Conn, error) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    origin := "http://localhost/"
    url := "ws://localhost:12345/ws"
    return websocket.Dial(url, "", origin)
}
 // wsServer returns the websocket
 // connections received on /ws endpoint
func wsServer() chan *websocket.Conn {
    wsCh := make(chan *websocket.Conn, 1)
    http.Handle("/ws", websocket.Handler(func(ws *websocket.Conn) {
        wsCh <- ws
        time.Sleep(1 *time.Hour)
    }))
    go func() {
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":12345", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
        }
    }()
    return wsCh
}
// wsToTCP reads a ws connection and converts its payload
// to a TCP connection.
func wsToTCP(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    conn := &net.TCPConn{}
    var msg []byte
    if _, err := ws.Read(msg); err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return
    }
    log.Infof("msg %v", msg)
    n, err := conn.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("conn.Write %v, msg %v", err, msg)
        return
    }
    log.Infof("conn is %v, copied %v", conn, n)
    // END: do something with the connection
    // ..... 
}
//ListenTCP returns the first TCP connection received on port 8080
func listenTCP() *net.TCPConn {
    addr := &net.TCPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("0.0.0.0"), Port: 8080}
    lr, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    }
    defer lr.Close()
    ieConn, err := lr.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Infof("connection accepted")
    return ieConn
}
```

To trigger the TCP listener you can issue a request on port 8080 (e.g. `curl --socks5 localhost:8080 google.com -v` or `curl localhost:8080 -v`)

Comment: Did you mean something like [wstunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wstunnel)  or [websockets-proxy](https://github.com/dmajda/websockets-proxy) ?

Comment: yeah, it seems wstunnel is what I mean though javascript is not my thing.

Comment: websockets-proxy seems to do the same thing too... is there any Go equivalent?

Comment: I don't know of an Go equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't be any problem. I've built TCP forwarders over a number of protocols. Never WebSockets, but I don't see a reason it would be different.

You have two problems:

- The correct way to make a connection is with `net.Dial`, not by just creating a `net.TCPConn`.
- You're only copying in one direction. You need to copy in both directions.

Here's a super simple proxy that I built this morning for a different purpose (my full code corrupts a packet every so often so I can test bad connectoins). It should be convertible to many other purposes:

```
func run(inPort int, dest string) {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", inPort))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("http://%v -> %s\n", l.Addr(), dest)

    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Connection from %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr())
        go proxy(conn, dest)
    }
}

func proxy(in net.Conn, dest string) {
    out, err := net.Dial("tcp", dest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    go io.Copy(out, in)
    io.Copy(in, out)
    fmt.Printf("Disconnect from %s\n", in.RemoteAddr())
}
```

You just need to replace the `net.Dial` here with a WS call to your server, and on the server side use `net.Dial` to forward it along.

But probably the most key point is the last few lines. You have to copy in both directions and people forget that.

Comment: just now I was thinking to use a "fake" listener and Dial to create the TCP connection.. I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems to be a dead end. I've updated my answer with the code I've tried. The ideal to have a "fake" listener and dialer just to construct a TCP connection seems wrong and doesn't work.

Comment: It's worth to note that in your example you have only two parties but I have 3 (NAT, Server and IE).

Comment: I've updated my answer with the final solution. Indeed I had to Dial a fake listener which I find very awkward (i.e. keeping listening on a local port and dialing it with the data received through websockets). I'm wondering if it would be possible to create a constructor for the net package to read from websockets (an io.ReadWriter) and return *net.Conn without the fake dialer/listener.